# D3js drag vs click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, d3.js

I'm coding a d3js tree with drag/drop and click features for the nodes. I come across this example http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/fe5gn/.

```
var container,
    rect,
    dragBehavior,
    wasDragged = false;

container = d3.select('svg')
    .append('g');

rect = container.append('rect')
    .attr('width', 100)
    .attr('height', 100);

dragBehavior = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragend', onDragStart)
    .on('drag', onDrag)
    .on('dragend', onDragEnd);

container
    .call(dragBehavior)
    .on('click', onClick);

function flashRect() {
    rect.attr('fill', 'red').transition().attr('fill', 'black');
}

function onDragStart() {
    console.log('onDragStart');
}

function onDrag() {
    console.log('onDrag');

    var x = (d3.event.sourceEvent.pageX - 50);

    container.attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ')');

    wasDragged = true;
}

function onDragEnd() {
    if (wasDragged === true) {
        console.log('onDragEnd');

        // always do this on drag end
        flashRect();
    }

    wasDragged = false;
}

function onClick(d) {
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented === false) {
        console.log('onClick');

        // only do this on click if we didn't just finish dragging
        flashRect();
    }
}
```

But this example doesn't act the same way as on chrome as on firefox.
When i click the rectangle:

- Chrome ouput: OnDrag, OnDragEnd, OnClick
- Firefox output: OnClick

When i drag and drop the rectangle:

- Chrome ouput: OnDrag, OnDragEnd
- Firefox output: OnDrag, OnDragEnd

Is there any way to make chrome behave the same way as firefox when clicking?

Comment: Im using Chromium and it beahaves like Firefox. If you add `d3.event.stopPropagation();`after `flashRect();` in onClick, doest it work?

Comment: @TimB add stopPropagation to onClick function will do nothing since i need to stop firing onDrag and onDrag is fired before onClick

Comment: I guess `.on('dragend', onDragStart)` should be `.on('dragstart', onDragStart)`

Answer (score 0):

```
   container
       .call(dragBehavior)
       .on('click', onClick);
```

to

```
   container
       .on("mousedown", function() { 
                d3.event.stopPropagation();

                d3.select(this).on("mouseup", onClick);
                d3.select(this).on("mousemove",  function()
                {
                    d3.select(this).call(dragBehavior);
                });
            });
```